# How to implement move semantics in a template class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, move, unique-ptr

I have a template class for a queue. I also would like be able to store objects contained in a std::unique_ptr.

Normal template specialization is not possible because the std::unique pointer can be instantiated with any type.

Queue code is like this:

```
bool TQueue<T>::Push(const T& item)
{
  m_Mem[currTail] = item;
}

bool TQueue<T>::Pop( T& item )
{
  item = m_Mem[currHead];
}
```

How to make this work for std::unique_ptr types as well, when I need to do m_Mem[curtail] = std::move(item)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're approaching the problem from a slightly wrong angle. The `move()` cannot be inside the `Push()`, that's too late. It must be outside - you cannot really steal the resources of an arbitrary argument, you must ask the user to actively move the non-copyable resource there. So simply provide an extra overload:

```
bool TQueue<T>::Push(const T& item)
{
  m_Mem[currTail] = item;
}

bool TQueue<T>::Push(T&& item)
{
  m_Mem[currTail] = std::move(item);
}
```

That way, your users can actively move their objects into the container when they want (by doing `queue.Push(std::move(my_object));`.

For `Pop()`, the situation is even simpler: `Pop()` removes an element from the queue, so you should always `move()` it out - you're not retaining any copies:

```
bool TQueue<T>::Pop( T& item )
{
  item = std::move(m_Mem[currHead]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! It seems indeed obvious. I will try it.

Comment: Any suggestion how to implement this for pop ? In this case I am not able to invoke the overload.